# Subscribe Observable value

Tags: typescript, angular, observable

When I'm logging the value of my variable inside the subscribe i have a value but when doing it outside it i get undefined ???:

```
this._postService.getConf("app/conf/conf.json")
   .subscribe(res =>{
      this.home = JSON.stringify(res);
      console.log("value :" + this.home);
```

i want to initialize my home variable with a certain value I'm doing it on ngOnInit but it get the value undefined when I'm trying to get it outside:

This is my function :

```
getConf(url) {
   return this._http.get(url).
      map(res => {return res.json()});
}

ngOnInit() {

  this._postService.getConf("app/conf/conf.json")
   .subscribe(res => {
        this.home = JSON.stringify(res);
        console.log("hahowaaaaaaaa" + this.home);
   }
  );

  this._postService.getPosts(this.home)
  .subscribe(result =>{ 
    this.loading = false;
    this.actionsG = result; 
    var count = JSON.stringify(result);

    this.aCount = count.substring(count.indexOf(','),23);

  },error=> console.error('Error: ' + error), ()=> console.log('finish! ActionsG'));

  this._postService.getPosts(this.home ).subscribe(result => this.actionsV = 
    result, error=> console.error('Error: ' + error), ()=> console.log('finish! ActionsV ngOnInit' + this.page));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how observables work. When the response from the server arrives, the callback passed to `subscribe(...)` is called by the observable.

The `console.log()` outside of `subscribe()` is executed before the call to the server is even made.

Comment: thank's for your answer , and how can i affect the value to my variable sir ? i was thinikg doing it on ngOnInit will fix it

Comment: What does "affect the value to my variable sir" mean? What variable? Affect how?

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't explain : i'm trying to get a json file that contains data on : ngOnInit to print data when loading the page, and the server link i'm getting it from a file and affecting it to my var home, so before getting data from server, i'm getting home value to push it through my service and i'm doing both this on ngOnInit, please don't hesitate to ask if you need more information

Comment: If you want to modify the response value you need to do it inside `map(...)` or `subscribe(...)`. Where you call `_postService.getConf()...` doesn't matter much.

Comment: yeah, but how could i delay it ? because when i call the services on ngOnInit they depend on my 'home' var value, i've edited my post so you can see ngOniti contains ..

Comment: I see. You need to use observable operators like `switchMap`. There are similar questions with answers. I can't help you here. I'm using Dart and there are biggere differences related to observables.

Answer (score 3):

My ngOnInit() had called a process that gets data from a DB.
I expected the `this.##` variables which were updated in the method to be available after the call.   As was described above, the call passes to observable, which means the variables are not available in ngOnInit().   But they were all populated when the HTML page displayed.

So the solution is to do all the needed work inside the method and then refer to variables which will be populated in HTML.

```
this.service.getCity(zip).subscribe(
    data => {
        if (data.errStatus == 0) {
            console.log("data: " +   data.xx.List);

            this.xx.List = data.xx.List;
            console.log("data2: " + this.xxList);
        } else {
            data.errText;
            console.log(data.errText);
        }
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done')
);
```